# Collect input from multiple fieldsets and display as dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having forms that ask for first and last name.

```
<fieldset id="id-hero[0]">
 <input type="text" name="f-hero[0]"/>
 <input type="text" name="l-hero[0]"/>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="id-hero[1]">
 <input type="text" name="f-hero[1]"/>
 <input type="text" name="l-hero[1]"/>
</fieldset>
```

Now, I have another form which stores the first and last name of the boss. The boss is one among the people entered above.

```
<fieldset id="id-boss" data-fill="id-hero">
 <input type="text" name="f-boss"/>
 <input type="text" name="l-boss"/>
</fieldset>
```

Is there a way by which we can collect all the first and last names entered in the above forms and give user a drop down in the Boss form of all available names that user doesnt have to type? Ideally, the user should only have to select the first name, the matching last name should come along with it.

A sample fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nmbcp80r/).

Comment: Yes there is a way. However, why don't you try doing some research on JavaScript and jQuery and how these things are done? That will teach you much more than having the volunteers on SO write code for you.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: I'd love to do that. I started with the documentation and was lost. I'm only looking for pointers.